# Где дописать, что бы прогресс бар начинался с 55% до 100%?

Tags: javascript, html, css

где дописать что бы прогресс бар начинался с 55% и доходил до 100%, не с 0 и до 100, а именно с 55% `https://jsfiddle.net/kazimirov_art/rgmv2ju3/85/`, прогресс бар с текстом поэтому, он сейчас не работает потому что в строчках выставлены эти значения

```
if (value >= 55 && value <= 71) {
circle.setText(value);
        text.innerHTML='Адаптация плана Марафона к Вашему плотному графику';
        } 

        if (value >= 72 && value <= 89) { 
        circle.setText(value); 
        text.innerHTML='Подбор подходящих Вам рецептов и тренировок';
        }
                if (value >= 90 && value <= 100) { 
        circle.setText(value); 
        text.innerHTML='Ваша индивидуальная программа похудения готова!';
        }
```

Но и еще один вопрос, но он легкий, как поставить что бы после чисел шел процент, пробовал стандартным методом, то есть сюда
const value = Math.round(circle.value() * 100) + "%";

```
 if (value >= 55 + "%"; && value <= 71 + "%";) { 
    circle.setText(value);
    text.innerHTML='Адаптация плана Марафона к Вашему плотному графику';
    } 

    if (value >= 72 + "%"; && value <= 89 + "%";) { 
    circle.setText(value); 
    text.innerHTML='Подбор подходящих Вам рецептов и тренировок';
    }
            if (value >= 90 + "%"; && value <= 100 + "%";) { 
    circle.setText(value); 
    text.innerHTML='Ваша индивидуальная программа похудения готова!';
    }
```

добавил знак %, но прогресс бар тогда сбивается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> добавил знак %, но прогресс бар тогда сбивается

потому что вы начинаете поганить число в переменной, пытаясь туда строку записать

процент надо в вывод ставить, а не в сравнения:

```
circle.setText(value + "%");
```

т.е.

```
if (value >= 55 && value <= 71) { 
    circle.setText(value + "%");
    text.innerHTML='Адаптация плана Марафона к Вашему плотному графику';
}
```

> где дописать что бы прогресс бар начинался с 55% и доходил до 100%, не
> с 0 и до 100, а именно с 55%

а вот тут вам лучше все таки привести какой-то работоспособный код в котором прогрессбар идет с 0 до 100,

что именно вам мешает самому устанавливать значения в нужном диапазоне?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kazimirov_art/rgmv2ju3/85/ вот код он не рабочий из за этих строк     
      if (value >= 55 && value <= 71) { 
        circle.setText(value);
        text.innerHTML='Адаптация плана Марафона к Вашему плотному графику';
        } 

        if (value >= 72 && value <= 89) { 
        circle.setText(value); 
        text.innerHTML='Подбор подходящих Вам рецептов и тренировок';
        }
                if (value >= 90 && value <= 100) { 
        circle.setText(value); 
        text.innerHTML='Ваша индивидуальная программа похудения готова!';
        } @Zhihar

Comment: Если числа вот так поставить, но то есть что бы начиналось с 0, он и будет рабочим, вот в этом проблем
if (value >= 0 && value <= 50) { 
        circle.setText(value);
        text.innerHTML='Адаптация плана Марафона к Вашему плотному графику';
        } 

        if (value >= 51 && value <= 80) { 
        circle.setText(value); 
        text.innerHTML='Подбор подходящих Вам рецептов и тренировок';
        }
                if (value >= 81 && value <= 100) { 
        circle.setText(value); 
        text.innerHTML='Ваша индивидуальная программа похудения готова!';
        } @Zhihar

Comment: А мне нужно что бы начинался с 55% @Zhihar

Comment: @Kazimirov_art, по присланной ссылке код не работает

Comment: вот вы говорите "должно начинаться с 55%", а если задать 40%, то что должно отображаться?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kazimirov_art/rgmv2ju3/88/ вот я изменил строки кода, теперь она рабочая, если задавать в этом коде if (value >= 0 && value <= 71) { circle.setText(value); , а именно строку value >= 0, поставить  value >= 1 или любое число выше то уже не работает потому что начинается, не с 0, а мне нужно что бы с 55% начиналось @Zhihar

Comment: вы используете стороннюю библиотеку прогресса, а вы уверены что в ней вообще есть такая возможность?

Comment: @Kazimirov_art Вчера видел ваш вопрос, еще раз продублируйте весь код а не его части в ваш вопрос там помойму при запуске функции есть входящие данные по типу числа 0 измените его на 55 и все должно работать

Comment: Здравствуйте, вот код jsfiddle.net/kazimirov_art/rgmv2ju3/88, спасибо Вам @pyduti